# SAPUI5 create multiple value(batch) using post

Tags: odata, sapui5, netweaver

To post data in the SAP Back-end I use:

```
oModel.create("/Dummyset", oEntry); //so far it works fine
```

Now I have multiple lines in my oEntry and it doesn't work. I found the following solution

```
aBatchOperation.push(contactBatchOperation);        
oModel.addBatchChangeOperations(aBatchOperation);
oModel.submitBatch(fSuccess,fError,true);
```

But unfortunately it's not working with my OData version 2.0 . I always get an error as

> "addBatchChangeOperations is not a function"

Then I tried to find out which function I can use with OData v2. I could find this.

```
batchChanges.push(oModel._createBatchRequest("/AttributesSet", "POST", wert.Atrributes[i].name));
oModel._submitBatchRequest(oModel.setProperty("/AttributesSet", batchChanges), true);
```

But it still does not work. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want to bundle several create requests into one batch, right?

For ODataModel [create](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#create) method, you can define additional groupId. See below.

> mParameters.**groupId**?  ID of a request group; requests belonging to the same group will be bundled in one batch request

Basically you can submit multiple **create** with the same **groupId** which you can define yourself.

First you have to set a certain [deferredGroups](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#setDeferredGroups) for ODataModel

```
var aDeferredGroup = oModel.getDeferredGroups().push("batchCreate");
oModel.setDeferredGroups(aDeferredGroup);
```

Then you call multiple create.

```
var mParameters = {groupId:"batchCreate"};
oModel.create("/Dummyset", oEntry1, mParameters);
oModel.create("/Dummyset", oEntry2, mParameters);
oModel.create("/Dummyset", oEntry3, mParameters);
```

At last, you can call [submitChanges](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#submitChanges) with one single batch for multiple requests.

```
oModel.submitChanges(mParameters);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I works, but not as desired. only the last item of oModel.create is inserted. I dont know, if I m doing something wrong in the back or in the front end.

Comment: You check the oData request in the Chrome dev tools to see whether the multiple requests are sent. If this is true, it should be the backend issue. You have to implement the backend changeset_begin, changeset_process, and changeset_end methods. You can check this post https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/94/a126519eff236ee10000000a445394/content.htm

Comment: So finally it works fine. I had the same oEntry value. That is why I thought it was not working. Thank you @Allen

Comment: is it not possible to pack all this oEntry in a one and then loop to create entries? When i try it with a for-loop, it only create the last entry although  oEntry value are different.

Comment: Solved!!   was just a declaration issue