# How to copy data from OData v4 to JSON with SAP UI5?

Tags: javascript, json, odata, sapui5

I'm using OData v4 to load data from my backend to my frontend (developed with SAP UI5) and I am using a form to display a detail page. When I click the "edit" button I'm able to edit the data. My implementation is similar to this example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.Form354/code/Page.controller.js

When editing something, the data is directly edited at the model and, therefore, updated at the backend. However, I want to be able to choose if I want to save the changes or if I want to cancel the edit before it is updated at the backend.

I read on other questions that one can copy the ODataModel to a JSONModel and use that copy instead, by doing something like:

```
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var oModelJson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.read("/Data", {
        success: function(oData, response) {
            oModelJson.setData(oData);
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModelJson, "oJSONModel");
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

However, the read method seems not to be available for OData v4. the code of my controller where the data is loaded looks like following:

```
onInit: function() {
    this.oModel = new ODataModel({
        groupId : "$direct",
        synchronizationMode : "None",
        serviceUrl : '/odata/'
    });

    this.getView().setModel(this.oModel, 'oModel');

    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.getRoute("details").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);

    this._showFormFragment("display");

},

_onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
    this.getView().bindElement({
        path: "/Data(" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").dataPath + ")",
        model: "oModel"
    });
    //I want to copy the data from the ODataModel to the JSONModel here
},
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? And how to do it with OData v4?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to resetChanges in case user cancels the save.

For V2 ODataModel, there is [deferedGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696398/sapui5-create-multiple-valuebatch-using-post/42698877#42698877) concept which you can use to resetChanges or submitChanges.

I have not much experience with V4. Though from the documentation, it is possible.

Please try to pass a updateGroupId in the [constructor](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel.html#constructor). Then you can choose [resetChanges](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel.html#resetChanges) or [submitBatch](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel.html#submitBatch) by group Id.

> mParameters.updateGroupId?    The group ID that is used for update requests. If no update group ID is specified, mParameters.groupId is used. Valid update group IDs are undefined, '$auto', '$direct' or an application group ID, which is a non-empty string consisting of alphanumeric characters from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I try to run resetChanges with groupID "$direct", I get an error message. And I seem not to be able to find how to set the deferedGroup with V4.

Comment: You cannot use a $ prefixed group. Please use a string matches /^\w+$/. see the isValidGroupId method at https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/_ODataHelper-dbg.js